# ng-model in input based on another variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I han an input filed in my angular app `<input type="text" ng-model="variableA">`. I want to use `variableA` or `variableB` basing on some condition. I've tried something like this `ng-model="condition ? variableA : variableB"` but it throws `Error: [ngModel:nonassign]`. Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: you can define a variableC for your 'root model' and assigns it conditionally to variableA or variableB at the beginning of your angular controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngModel` has to be a property expression (following the fules of $parse).

Try using a proxy then watch that variable to then assign to A or B:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="variableC">
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('variableC', function(value) {

  if(someCondition) {
    $scope.variableA = value;
  } else { 
    $scope.variableB = value;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Wawy's answer is good too, but I'm still using angular 1.2 (ie8 support...).

Answer (score 5):

You could make use of [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="setModel" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}">
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.setModel = function(value) {
  var model = '';
  if (condition) {
    model = "variableA";
  } else {
    model = "variableB";
  }

  if (angular.isDefined(value)) {
    return ($scope[model] = value);
  } else {
    return $scope[model];
  } 
};
```

Comment: Can you give more information with this one? I have read in docs but I still don't understand :(

Comment: @Elec what don't you understand?

Comment: @Wawy What is parameter `value` assigned ? and Why you have to assign `$scope[model] = value`. Sorry it's newbie question,but I have no idea why have to do it.

Comment: When getterSetter: true is used, ngModel calls the function you define as the attribute value of ngModel in two ways, one way when it wants to read the value, as $scope.setModel(), and the other way when it wants to set the value in the model $scope.setModel(value). You are responsible for handling the getting and setting of the model in your function.

Comment: @Wawy Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<input type="text" ng-model="variableC">
```

and in controller

```
$scope.variableC = (condition) ? variableA : variableB
```